# Adding CSS to HTML file or Typescript file for Webpack to load

Tags: html, css, typescript, webpack

I'm kind of new to web dev. I have a site with all HTML and CSS laid out and organized. There is no functioning logic yet, which is going to be my next task. I've been setting up Webpack for most of the day, and I'm stuck on the last step of loading CSS. Most of the HTML files include an external CSS in the shape of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">`. I can get Webpack to load these CSS when I explicitly import them in the companion TS files. However, that feels a little redundant to me. Can't Webpack be set up to find and load CSS from the `<link>` tags in HTML templates rather than the imports in TS? Or is the convention to do it in TS? I can't seem to find any specifics on this.

I've spent quite a bit of time to try and load CSS from HTML templates (so far to no avail), and that made me question if it's even the right approach.

Comment: are you using html webpack plugin?

Comment: @3Demon yes I am

Comment: Please add in your question a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's very difficult to suggest solution when there is no information about what loader, plugins, configuration you are using...